# SMTP: Setup TWO servers to receive / store emails the same at the same time

Tags: postfix, smtp

My question aims to clarify whether I can get a setup running, where Server A on 1 site receives email as is received at the same time by Server B on site two.

The requirement is to have Server B be failed to in case Server A is inaccessible, or down; but at any given moment, users will be using one of the two.

The setup I know is that one server can temporarily receive email for the other whilst its done, but then forward, using two or three MX records with differing priorities

e.g.

MX 10 mail.example.com
MX 20 mail.example.com

but how do you make it that each and every email is sent to both servers, and one server is used as sending server by users?

Take note, this is platform open, meaning I would also allow answers suggesting platforms, but so far these are my platforms

1. Zentyal 4.1: Postfix, Dovecot, OpenChange

**Update**
IN WHAT WAY (preferably using Zentyal setup above) can I setup Server B to get the same email that Server A gets (even by forwards, or whatever TRICK): if this is possible, or can be achieved, and in what way. I have researched and can't find clarity on this matter if this is a STANDARD or you have to achieve it by the TRICK. What I want is whether its possible, if not WHY.

ULTIMATELY, the feel should be that when Server A is down, Server B is connected to by both users sending email, and for receiving email into the mail store (Which can be explained if it is one or more, however ONE still leaves the problem of a failure with that mail store), and users connect to it for IMAP and POP3

Comment: Are both servers mirrors of one another (ie, are they both running the same software stack)?

Comment: MS Exchange does all of this, not at the MX level (and it can't be done at that level) but at the email database level. Look at database availability groups.

Comment: are the 2 servers on the same physical LAN?

Comment: Can not be done. An email always arrives at one server. There are mechanisms to synchronize content on multiple servers, but they always come with a (possibly miniscule) time delay. And both servers will not RECEIVE the email at the same time. So, as the question stands now (granted, it is VERY badly or naively worded) it is not doable.

Comment: what is the problem with 2 or more MXs?

Comment: Thanks for your comments: @mjturner, YES, they run the same software stack.

Comment: @Skaperen NO, we want one to be residing at another site

Comment: @Drifter104: An Exchange DAG doesn't provide the ability for a user to be connected to either/any database copy. The user will be connected to the active database copy. Furthermore, email isn't delivered to all database copies, email is delivered to the active database copy and is then copied to all other database copies.

Comment: @joeqwerty You create a DAG with two databases, one live on each site. Effectively all the users from one site are in one database (or more this scales), Mail is delivered to one site (ideally the site with the most amount of users) via mx it will then route mail for the other users to the other server. When a server goes down fail the dag over and mail is delivered to the still up server via the alternative mx record. Primary mx = primary site, second mx = other site. Scale everything above as required

Comment: My point is that a user connects to whichever mailbox server holds the active database copy where their mailbox exists. It's not an either or proposition.

Comment: @joeqwerty and Drifter104, you guys seem to have answers, or par-answers, please check my **edit**

Comment: The SMTP part - receiving the messages on two servers is simple enough, forward a copy of everything Server1 receives to Server2.  The hard part is syncing the datastore between the two servers.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using (IMAP server) [dovecot's replication](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Replication)?